# Использование reflection в Golang

Tags: golang, рефлексия

Добрый день, пытаюсь разобраться с reflection и тегами в структурах в Go, на примере конфигурации для приложения

Есть код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "flag"
)

type AppConfig struct {
    Pg    string `cli:"pg"    env:"PG"    default:"host=host.local dbname=db user=user password=password" description:"Connection to PostgreSQL"`
    Redis string `cli:"redis" env:"REDIS" default:"host.local"                                            description:"Redis server"`
}

func main() {
    config := GetConfig(&AppConfig{})
    fmt.Println(config)
}

func GetConfig(config *AppConfig) *AppConfig {
    ref := reflect.TypeOf(*config)
    value := reflect.ValueOf(*config)
    for i := 0; i < value.NumField(); i++ {
        field := ref.Field(i)

        name := field.Tag.Get("env")
        if name != "" {
            env := os.Getenv(name)
            if env != "" {
                value.Field(i).SetString(env)
            } else {
                def := field.Tag.Get("default")
                if def != "" {
                    value.Field(i).SetString(def)
                }
            }
        }
        /*
            cli := field.Tag.Get("cli")
            if cli != "" {
                flag.StringVar((*string)(value.Field(i).Pointer()), cli, value.Field(i).String(), field.Tag.Get("description"))
            }
        */
    }
    flag.Parse()
    return config
}
```

Песочница: https://play.golang.org/p/b7bDUd-mj-
Получаю

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetString using unaddressable value
```

Чувствую что что-то простое упускаю, но вот что?

P.S. В за-комментированном участке работа с command-line флагами, но тут моего понимания того что там происходит не хватает

Comment: Всем спасибо разобрался, окончательная версия того что получилось https://play.golang.org/p/Aiz01U-gzK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема тут:

```
value := reflect.ValueOf(*config)
```

Из-за того, что вы разименовываете указатель, вы получаете значение `AppConfig`. Его нельзя изменить. Почему? Потому что по сути вы делаете вот так:

```
func setX(x int) { x = 2 }
```

То есть, обращаетесь по значению, а не по ссылке. Такая функция *не изменит оригинальный `x`*. Однако такая изменит:

```
func setX(x *int) { *x = 2 }
```

Вам нужно в вашей функции делать

```
value := reflect.ValueOf(config)
```

а дальше обращаться по `value.Elem()`. Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZKCsS-82v-.

См. также [Третий Закон Отражения](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_8.).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, хотелось еще один вопрос про рефлексии уточнить: до private полей (которые с маленькой буквы) до них не добраться?

Comment: Не private, а unexported. И да, установить вы их не сможете. См. доку [`CanSet`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet).

Comment: Да, спасибо за уточнение, пока путаюсь в формулироваках :-)
Кстати про, то как преобразовать value.Field(i).Pointer() в *string - не осилил, то есть хотелось-бы получить из рефлексии ссылку на значение нужного типа.

Comment: @chernomyrdin Это не для комментов. Если не осилите, напишите лучше новый вопрос с конкретным примером, что у вас есть и что надо сделать.